# Which Java web frameworks is better in performance and in fast development?

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, web-frameworks

I have new web applications needed to be built from scratch. I need to choose/compare which java web frameworks is better in performance and rapid development.

Comment: You could check this page to get an overview of common web frameworks for Java: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-curious-coders-java-web-frameworks-comparison-spring-mvc-grails-vaadin-gwt-wicket-play-struts-and-jsf/11/

Answer (score 1):

If you want rapid development in java, play  framework is a good choice. Though you have to deal with flavors of scala few times.

If you want something more stable and with lots of documentaion and examples, spring framwork with gradle/maven has me develop applications rapidly in java.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a pretty loaded question and the answer is going to be a bit hit and miss.

Performance wise, my experience is not to use any particular framework, but build the individual stack components by hand (this is fairly trivial using maven, and most things play well with others) for robustness tho' Spring is definitely a one stop shop. My personal favorite though is a ZK/Guava/Shiro/jOOQ stack, because it offers a good trade-off.

As far as rapid development goes, what you are familiar with, and depending on how rapid we're talking, Java may not even be the right thing compared to Python/Django and PHP/Angular/CodeIgniter. Play Framework and Spring Roo bring a lot to the table with regards to rapid development, I'm not arguing that. But for the first couple of sites, the learning curve can be somewhat costly, particularly if you already have a working stack that your developers already know. So it depends. If it's a handful of sites, don't bother, if it's more than that, Play or Roo are both good options.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you will understand clearly see this zk forum question:http://forum.zkoss.org/question/90582/why-zk-framework-rather-than-others/#90730

ZK is a great framework Because of

(1) easy to learn

(2) very productive

(3) most important

(4) best architecture - it puts MVC,MVVM, databinding, server+client and server-push together elegantly.